# how do I concatenate a variable container using a variable+ a string

Tags: javascript

```js
type = "grass"
grassStrong = ["water", "ground", "rock"];
console.log(this[type + "Strong"])
```

Is there a way to get something like this to work? i have multiple lists that are "type" strong, "type" weak and it would be much easier to use these lists if I can just concatenate the container in this way. I want to put 2 strings together to get a variable

Comment: What is the `this` here?

Comment: This question should not have been closed. OP's example was just how they're currently doing it, and they want to know what the correct way to do it is.

Comment: In practice, you never need — or _want_, really — dynamic variable names. Use a simple object instead: `const strength = "strong"; const types = { grass: { weak: [`…`], strong: [ "water", "ground", "rock" ] } };` … `console.log(obj[type][strength]);`, or something similar.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Your comment would have been better posted as an answer, no?

Comment: @geshode, not sure, but when i added it originally it worked with no issue... now it isn't for some reason lol

Comment: @SebastianSimon
```
strongType = {
normal:[""],
fire:["grass", "ice", "bug", "steel"],
water:["fire", "ground", "rock"],
grass:["water", "ground", "rock"],
}

pickType="grass"
console.log(strongType.pickType)
```
so i tried this but still having similar issues

Comment: @ReinkDesigns You need to use bracket notation, otherwise you're trying to access the key `pickType`, not the key stored within that variable. `strongType[pickType]` (this is shown and mentioned in the link above your question, I suggest giving that a read first if you haven't yet)

Comment: @NickParsons AHH ok makes sence